# QGIS - error added after processing

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, topology

I use the "difference" processing beetwen 2 layers to have polygons of layers A that do not intersect polygons of layer B. In these 2 layers there are not bad geometries and topology is cleaned. I checked for that with "check geometry and "verify topology"

After the difference, in the result layer I detected a lot of errors: **duplicate nodes and self-intersection**. The results is often flats polygons as we see on illustration below.

**I would like to know why errors appear** while layers A and B are clean. maybe problem of tpology beetwen A and B ?

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know, why these errors appear? Do you want to know, how to avoid these errors? Or do you want to know, how to remedy the produced errors?

Comment: sorry... I want to know why errors appear.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail, how you intersect/clip the two layers? Please edit your post accordingly, thank you.